# Pcre regular expression to ignore newlines

Tags: pcre

I've a PCRE regular expression of the following form:

```
Foo:\\s*(.*)
```

When this is used to match Foo: bar\n then the group match contains the newline also.
How can I change the regular expression to remove the newline from the group match.

Answer (score 0):

If you can turn off *`.` matches `\n`* then do that.

Otherwise, place an optional newline at the end.

```
Foo:\\s*(.*)\n?
```

Or you could swap `(.*)` with `(\S*)`

Comment: Furthermore \S* won't work because I need to match the spaces in the group. Also, \\n does not seem to work either

Comment: @ajay Did you use `\\n` or `\n` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo:[^\\S\\r\\n]*(.*)
```

This will match whitespace but not Carriage Return (\r) or New Line (\n). If you find that `.*` is matching newlines too you can change the expression to:

```
Foo:[^\\S\\r\\n]*([^\\r\\n]*)
```